# Insert gives error code 1366 even though charset is utf8mb4

Tags: mysql, mariadb, encoding, rocksdb

I am trying to manually copy a table from one server to another.
I used mysqldump to export the table. The import fails with the following error:

```
ERROR 1366 (22007) at line 6: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9D\x97\x96\xF0\x9D...' for column `MYDB`.`MYTABLE`.`field` at row 8142
```

I read everywhere that this is usually an issue with charset and collation. However, I have checked and both servers have the same charset and collation.

Here is the command I used to export my table:

```
root@master:/var/# mysqldump -uMYUSER -pMYPASSWORD MYDB MYTABLE > MYTABLE_bkp/MYTABLE.sql
```

Here is the table on the first server (data source):

```
MariaDB [MYDB]> show create table MYTABLE;
+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         |
+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| MYTABLE | CREATE TABLE `MYTABLE` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sub_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `field` varchar(5000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field_h` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`sub_id`),
  KEY `i_opti_field_id` (`id`),
  KEY `i_opti_field_h` (`field_h`),
  KEY `i_opti_field_did` (`sub_id`)
) ENGINE=ROCKSDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3594408836 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci
 PARTITION BY HASH (`id`)
PARTITIONS 50 |
+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.020 sec)
```

Here is the command I used to import the data to the second server:

```
root@slave1:/var/db_backup# mariadb -uMYUSER -pMYPASSWORD MYDB < MYTABLE.sql
ERROR 1366 (22007) at line 6: Incorrect string value: '\xF0\x9D\x97\x96\xF0\x9D...' for column `MYDB`.`MYTABLE`.`field` at row 8142
```

And here is the table on the second server (data destination):

```
MariaDB [MYDB]> show create table MYTABLE;
+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Table | Create Table                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          |
+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| MYTABLE | CREATE TABLE `MYTABLE` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `sub_id` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `field` varchar(5000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `field_h` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`sub_id`)
) ENGINE=ROCKSDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci
 PARTITION BY HASH (`id`)
PARTITIONS 50 |
+-------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.019 sec)
```

I have tried to change the collation of the table (dumping then re-creating the table) on the second server to `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` but it did not help (same error).
I have also tried to change the charset/collation of the field explicitly to `utf8mb4` and `utf8mb4_unicode_ci` but it did not help either.

```
ALTER TABLE MYTABLE CHANGE column field VARCHAR(5000) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

My MariaDB version is the same on both servers:

```
mariadb  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.6.12-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (x86_64) using  EditLine wrapper
```

In case you wonder, there are a few differences between source and target tables. I removed 3 keys to speed up import. I also removed the `AUTO_INCREMENT` option as I don't need it on the target table.
Just so you know everything, the second server is a a slave, and I am trying to rebuild this table after an issue.
My alternative right now is to rebuild the whole slave database with `mariabackup` as per documentation, but it's massive (and used in production) so I'd like to avoid this.

Comment: The `COLLATION` is irrelevant.  The encoding needs to be `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4`, as you have it.

Answer (score 4):

Actually I needed to set the charset for the connection too. I thought that because I was using the `mariadb` command, there was no connection, but that was very naïve.

```
mariadb -uMYUSER -pMYPASSWORD --default-character-set=utf8mb4 MYDB < MYTABLE.sql
```

I'll leave the question as is because it might help someone some day.

Comment: kudos for a well written question, and for answering it, too.